# ¿Como saber el estado de clickado de un href con javascript /json?

Tags: javascript, json

tengo el siguiente codigo, que al ser clickado un ahref en especifico muestra la lista de usuario,pero tengo un método que cada cierto tiempo ejecuta el mismo método para obtener la lista actual, ¿como puedo hacer para obtener el estado clickado del ahref,para que el metodo de actualizarse cada cierto tiempo solo se ejecute si ha sido clikado la ultima ves el href de lista ?

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#user_list', function () {
        //muestra la lista
        getUserList(this);

    });
$(document).on('click', 'a#user_form', function () {
        //muestra formulario
        showUserform(this);

    });
//actualiza cada cierto tiempo
$(document).ready(function() {
  var refreshId =  setInterval( function(){
  //muestra la lista
        getUserList(this);
   }, 'json');
 }

 }, 1000 );
 });
```

Comment: Vos queres que la actualización automática se reinicie cada vez que haces click en el enlace?

Comment: si cada vez que se haga clic en el enlace de lista ,y mientras que no se haga clic en otro enlace que se actualice .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tenes que deshabilitar el interval cada vez que hacen click en un enlace distinto al de refrescar la lista y habilitarlo cuando hacen click en este últimpo

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //declaro la variable que guarda el interval
    var interval;

    $(document).on('click', 'a#user_list', function () {
        //muestra la lista
        getUserList();

        //activo el refresco automatico
        interval = setInterval(getUserList, 1000);
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'a#user_form', function () {

        //desactivo la actualizacion automatica
        clearInterval(interval);

        //muestra formulario
        showUserform(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: pero tengo un monton de hrefs  a todos deberia poner lo mismo,crees que ese es la unica solución? y gracias.

Comment: solo tenes que agregarselo a los enlaces que deban detener la actualización automática. podes seleccionar varios elementos para aplicarles el onclick con jquery.

Comment: yo solo quiero obtener el ultimo pulsado,no me importan los demas algo como esto: if((a#user_list).fueElUltimoenSerClikado){  interval = setInterval(getUserList, 1000);t}  , solo si este ultimo fue clikeado,los demas no me importa

Comment: No se entiende muy bien. Vos necesitas que si presionan el enlace #user_list se active el refresco automático, pero si se presiona cualquier otro enlace en la página se detenga el refresco automático. ¿Es correcto?

Comment: Que te parece un onclick a todos los elementos a y un condicionador que verifique si el #user_list que se clickeo